# setBadgeCount() not working after running electron-builder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, electron-builder

`setBadgeCount()` is not working after running `electron-builder`

Everything is working when running locally, but when I run `yarn electron-builder` the distributed app does not update the badge count, no matter what method I use. I've check the build folder inside my repo and the compiled function is there. The breaking step is somewhere in the `electron-builder` deployment.

`electron: "^8.2.3"`

`electron-builder: "^22.5.1"`

### React Component

```
const { app } = window.require('electron').remote;

function openCountText(count) {
  let badgeCount = `(${count}) `;
  if (!count) badgeCount = '';
  if (count > 9) badgeCount = '(9+) ';

  // Sets the badge count on the Desktop Application
  !!count && !!app && app.dock.setBadgeCount(count)

  return badgeCount;
}
```

#### Variations (Some of these methods are deprecated)

```
  !!count && !!app && app.dock.setBadge(`${count}`)
  !!count && !!app && app.dock.setBadge("19")
  !!count && !!app && app.setBadgeCount(2)
```

Comment: The same for me. Anyone found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

try to use :

```
const { app } = require('electron');
let badgeCount = 0;
    
app.setBadgeCount(badgeCount + 1);
// `0` will hide the badge.
app.setBadgeCount(badgeCount = 0);
```

docs https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appsetbadgecountcount-linux-macos